# If string in first line meets criteria and second line meets other criteria then

Tags: python

I have .txt file with lots of lines and i have trouble figuring out how to create program that will check line of the file, if in this line is string with code and in next line is other string i need then it will print out code

```
obsah = subor.readline()

kod = "K000178"
for line in subor:
    if kod in line:
        county += 1
        print("yes")
        more = next(obsah)
        if "Meno" in more:
            print("Yes Yes oh my god")
    else:
        print("oh no")
subor.close()
```

Comment: So what do you expect from this code and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
kod = "K000178"
flag = False
for line in subor:
    if flag and "Meno" in line:
        print(kod)
    flag = kod in line
else:
    print("oh no")
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: basically i need it to check if in .txt file is code in one line and in next line is "meno" then it prints code if you understand what i mean

Comment: Well, I believe this is what the program above does. Also please decide if it should be "meno" or "Meno", or either.

Comment: it should be Meno

Comment: also its not working because it will only print out "oh no" several times

Comment: Nope, it should print "oh no" only once and only if `kod` does not appear in the line before the one containing `"Meno"`.

Comment: Erm, are you sure your file meets your criteria? In particular, in which line `K000178` appears?

Comment: my file is specifically made to fits it and its 78-th line